# Lagom create static µ-service cluster

Tags: scala, docker, docker-compose, lagom

i wrote a few µ-services with lagom.
I have a docker-compose file in which all µ-services will be manual created.
Now I have a problem.
If I use discovery with akka-dns their is nothing found.
If I use static and give them the exposed ports their is also not found. Where is my mistake?

Docker compose file:

```
  security:
    container_name: panakeia-security
    image: nexus.familieschmidt.online/andre-user/panakeia/security-impl:latest
    environment:
      - APPLICATION_SECRET=hlPlU12MK?[oF1Xj`>xd>CtCjTHohfu0=ekVFOo?r]lH^GpFo5o?kurLFO6sQPzD
      - POSTGRESQL_URL=jdbc:postgresql://****SERVER-IP****:12000/panakeia
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=panakeia
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=123456789
      - INIT_USERNAME=test@test.de
      - INIT_USERPASS=123456
      - REQUIRED_CONTACT_POINT_NR=1
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Dconfig.resource=prod-application.conf -Dplay.server.pidfile.path=/dev/null
    expose:
      - 9000
      - 15000
#      - 8558
    ports:
      - "15000:15000"
      - "14999:9000"
    networks:
      - panakeia-network
```

My loader class

```
class SecurityLoader extends LagomApplicationLoader {

  override def load(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication =
    new SecurityApplication(context) with ConfigurationServiceLocatorComponents {
//      override def staticServiceUri: URI = URI.create("http://localhost:9000")
    }  //AkkaDiscoveryComponents

  override def loadDevMode(context: LagomApplicationContext): LagomApplication =
    new SecurityApplication(context) with LagomDevModeComponents

  override def describeService = Some(readDescriptor[SecurityService])

}
```

and my production.conf

```
include "application"

play {
    server {
        pidfile.path = "/dev/null"
    }

    http.secret.key = "${APPLICATION_SECRET}"
}

db.default {
    url = ${POSTGRESQL_URL}
    username = ${POSTGRESQL_USERNAME}
    password = ${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
}

user.init {
    username = ${INIT_USERNAME}
    password = ${INIT_USERPASS}
}

pac4j.jwk = {"kty":"oct","k":${JWK_KEY},"alg":"HS512"}

lagom.persistence.jdbc.create-tables.auto = true

//akka {
//  discovery.method = akka-dns
//
//  cluster {
//      shutdown-after-unsuccessful-join-seed-nodes = 60s
//  }
//
//  management {
//      cluster.bootstrap {
//          contact-point-discovery {
//              discovery-method = akka.discovery
////                discovery-method = akka-dns
//              service-name = "security-service"
//              required-contact-point-nr = ${REQUIRED_CONTACT_POINT_NR}
//          }
//      }
//  }
//}

lagom.services {
    security-impl = "http://****SERVER-IP****:15000"
//  serviceB = "http://10.1.2.4:8080"
}
```

For other domains on the same server i have a reverse nginx. But not for this project.
When I run http://****SERVER-IP****:14999 in browser I get a 404 NotFound typical Play screen message. :(

I have no problem to write the compose file and to link them manual. I have also no problem to use akka-dns. But I will have no kubernetes or something else.

Thanks for you help

Here is a log of one the µ-service

```
2021-04-02T14:38:24.151Z [info] akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger [] - Slf4jLogger started
2021-04-02T14:38:24.409Z [info] akka.remote.artery.tcp.ArteryTcpTransport [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=ArteryTcpTransport(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:24.409UTC] - Remoting started with transport [Artery tcp]; listening on address [akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520] with UID [-580933006609059378]
2021-04-02T14:38:24.427Z [info] akka.cluster.Cluster [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=Cluster(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:24.427UTC] - Cluster Node [akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520] - Starting up, Akka version [2.6.8] ...
2021-04-02T14:38:24.527Z [info] akka.cluster.Cluster [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=Cluster(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:24.527UTC] - Cluster Node [akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
2021-04-02T14:38:24.528Z [info] akka.cluster.Cluster [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=Cluster(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:24.527UTC] - Cluster Node [akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520] - Started up successfully
2021-04-02T14:38:24.552Z [info] akka.cluster.Cluster [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.internal-dispatcher-2, akkaSource=Cluster(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:24.552UTC] - Cluster Node [akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520] - No downing-provider-class configured, manual cluster downing required, see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster.html#downing
2021-04-02T14:38:24.552Z [info] akka.cluster.Cluster [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.internal-dispatcher-2, akkaSource=Cluster(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:24.552UTC] - Cluster Node [akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520] - No seed-nodes configured, manual cluster join required, see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster.html#joining
2021-04-02T14:38:25.383Z [info] akka.io.DnsExt [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=DnsExt(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:25.383UTC] - Creating async dns resolver async-dns with manager name SD-DNS
2021-04-02T14:38:25.386Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.ClusterBootstrap [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=ClusterBootstrap(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:25.386UTC] - Bootstrap using default `akka.discovery` method: AggregateServiceDiscovery
2021-04-02T14:38:25.394Z [info] akka.management.internal.HealthChecksImpl [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=HealthChecksImpl(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:25.394UTC] - Loading readiness checks List(NamedHealthCheck(cluster-membership,akka.management.cluster.scaladsl.ClusterMembershipCheck))
2021-04-02T14:38:25.394Z [info] akka.management.internal.HealthChecksImpl [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=HealthChecksImpl(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:25.394UTC] - Loading liveness checks List()
2021-04-02T14:38:25.488Z [info] akka.management.scaladsl.AkkaManagement [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=AkkaManagement(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:25.488UTC] - Binding Akka Management (HTTP) endpoint to: 192.168.0.5:8558
2021-04-02T14:38:25.541Z [info] akka.management.scaladsl.AkkaManagement [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=AkkaManagement(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:25.541UTC] - Including HTTP management routes for ClusterHttpManagementRouteProvider
2021-04-02T14:38:25.581Z [info] akka.management.scaladsl.AkkaManagement [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=AkkaManagement(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:25.581UTC] - Including HTTP management routes for ClusterBootstrap
2021-04-02T14:38:25.585Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.ClusterBootstrap [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=ClusterBootstrap(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:25.584UTC] - Using self contact point address: http://192.168.0.5:8558
2021-04-02T14:38:25.600Z [info] akka.management.scaladsl.AkkaManagement [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=AkkaManagement(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:25.600UTC] - Including HTTP management routes for HealthCheckRoutes
2021-04-02T14:38:26.108Z [info] akka.management.scaladsl.AkkaManagement [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18, akkaSource=AkkaManagement(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:26.108UTC] - Bound Akka Management (HTTP) endpoint to: 192.168.0.5:8558
2021-04-02T14:38:26.154Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.ClusterBootstrap [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=ClusterBootstrap(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:26.154UTC] - Initiating bootstrap procedure using akka.discovery method...
2021-04-02T14:38:26.163Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5, akkaSource=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:26.163UTC] - Locating service members. Using discovery [akka.discovery.aggregate.AggregateServiceDiscovery], join decider [akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.LowestAddressJoinDecider]
2021-04-02T14:38:26.164Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5, akkaSource=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:26.163UTC] - Looking up [Lookup(application,None,Some(tcp))]
2021-04-02T14:38:26.189Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5, akkaSource=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:26.189UTC] - Located service members based on: [Lookup(application,None,Some(tcp))]: [], filtered to []
2021-04-02T14:38:26.195Z [info] play.api.db.DefaultDBApi [] - Database [default] initialized
2021-04-02T14:38:26.200Z [info] play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool [] - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
2021-04-02T14:38:26.207Z [info] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [] - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-02T14:38:26.218Z [info] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [] - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-04-02T14:38:26.221Z [info] play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool [] - datasource [default] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
2021-04-02T14:38:26.469Z [info] akka.cluster.sharding.ShardRegion [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.internal-dispatcher-4, akkaSource=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520/system/sharding/ProfileProcessor, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:26.469UTC] - ProfileProcessor: Idle entities will be passivated after [2.000 min]
2021-04-02T14:38:26.480Z [info] akka.cluster.sharding.typed.scaladsl.ClusterSharding [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=main, akkaSource=ClusterSharding(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:26.480UTC] - Starting Shard Region [ProfileEntity]...
2021-04-02T14:38:26.483Z [info] akka.cluster.sharding.ShardRegion [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.internal-dispatcher-3, akkaSource=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520/system/sharding/ProfileEntity, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:26.483UTC] - ProfileEntity: Idle entities will be passivated after [2.000 min]
2021-04-02T14:38:26.534Z [info] play.api.Play [] - Application started (Prod) (no global state)
2021-04-02T14:38:26.553Z [info] play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer [] - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000
2021-04-02T14:38:27.188Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.LowestAddressJoinDecider [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5, akkaSource=LowestAddressJoinDecider(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:27.187UTC] - Discovered [0] contact points, confirmed [0], which is less than the required [2], retrying
2021-04-02T14:38:27.363Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5, akkaSource=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:27.363UTC] - Looking up [Lookup(application,None,Some(tcp))]
2021-04-02T14:38:27.369Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19, akkaSource=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:27.369UTC] - Located service members based on: [Lookup(application,None,Some(tcp))]: [], filtered to []
2021-04-02T14:38:28.183Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.LowestAddressJoinDecider [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19, akkaSource=LowestAddressJoinDecider(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:28.183UTC] - Discovered [0] contact points, confirmed [0], which is less than the required [2], retrying
2021-04-02T14:38:28.563Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5, akkaSource=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:28.563UTC] - Looking up [Lookup(application,None,Some(tcp))]
2021-04-02T14:38:28.564Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18, akkaSource=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:28.564UTC] - Located service members based on: [Lookup(application,None,Some(tcp))]: [], filtered to []
2021-04-02T14:38:29.183Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.LowestAddressJoinDecider [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5, akkaSource=LowestAddressJoinDecider(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:29.183UTC] - Discovered [0] contact points, confirmed [0], which is less than the required [2], retrying
2021-04-02T14:38:29.724Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22, akkaSource=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:29.723UTC] - Looking up [Lookup(application,None,Some(tcp))]
2021-04-02T14:38:29.729Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.internal.BootstrapCoordinator [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18, akkaSource=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520/system/bootstrapCoordinator, sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:29.729UTC] - Located service members based on: [Lookup(application,None,Some(tcp))]: [], filtered to []
2021-04-02T14:38:30.183Z [info] akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.LowestAddressJoinDecider [akkaAddress=akka://application@192.168.0.5:25520, sourceThread=application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18, akkaSource=LowestAddressJoinDecider(akka://application), sourceActorSystem=application, akkaTimestamp=14:38:30.183UTC] - Discovered [0] contact points, confirmed [0], which is less than the required [2], retrying
```

It looks like the startup process is completly going wrong.
Inside of the securityapplication class it should be generated a user with this code

```
val newUUID = UUID.randomUUID()
          clusterSharding.entityRefFor(Profile.typedKey,newUUID.toString).ask[ProfileConfirmation](reply => CreateProfile(username,password,Some(EmailAddress(username)),Set(SuperAdminRole), PersonalData("","",""),reply ))(30.seconds).map{
            case ProfileCmdAccepted(profile) => s"Profile ${profile.login} created"
            case ProfileCmdRejected(err) => s"ERROR while default user init: $err"
            case a => s"a: $a"
          }
```

But there is throwing a Timeout exception. I think the cluster service is not initialized. At demo all working.
Do someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Okay found it

in the production conf I added

```
lagom.services {
    security-service = "http://"${REMOTE_IP}":15000"
    binary-service = "http://"${REMOTE_IP}":15001"
}

lagom.cluster.bootstrap.enabled = false
```

In the lagom Application loader in method load I inheriated my application from

```
ConfigurationServiceLocatorComponents
```

And now really important!
The docker must configured!
I used docker compose.
First adding a netowrk!

```
networks:
  panakeia-network:
#    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

AND now I give the cluster.seed-nodes.0 the ip of the service! And name the system! That is also important!

```
security:
    container_name: panakeia-security
    image: security-impl:latest
    environment:
      - APPLICATION_SECRET=****
      - POSTGRESQL_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-database:5432/panakeia
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=????
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=******
      - INIT_USERNAME=test@test.de
      - INIT_USERPASS=*******
      - JWK_KEY=******
      - REQUIRED_CONTACT_POINT_NR=1
      - KAFKA_BROKER=REALLY_IP/OR_KAFKA_SERVICE_NAME:9092
      - REMOTE_IP=????
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Dconfig.resource=prod-application.conf -Dplay.server.pidfile.path=/dev/null -Dakka.cluster.seed-nodes.0=akka://panakeia@172.28.1.5:25520 -Dplay.akka.actor-system=panakeia
    expose:
      - 9000
      - 15000
    ports:
      - "15000:15000"
      - "14999:9000"
    networks:
      panakeia-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.5
```

With this way it looks like it possible to create a simple and small µ-services cluster without complex systems like kubernetes.